SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Table Properties Timeout Issue
I'm encountering an issue in SQL Server 2019 when using SSMS (versions 20.2 and 21 preview). Navigating to a table and opening the "Properties" dialog consistently results in a timeout.
After some investigation, I discovered the problem stems from the underlying query executed by SSMS:
EXEC sp_executesql
   N'
        CREATE TABLE #tmp_extended_remote_data_archive_tables
        (object_id int not null, remote_table_name nvarchar(128) null, filter_predicate nvarchar(max) null, migration_state tinyint null)
 
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM master.sys.syscolumns WHERE Name = N''remote_data_archive_migration_state'' AND ID = Object_ID(N''sys.tables''))
        EXECUTE(N''INSERT INTO #tmp_extended_remote_data_archive_tables SELECT rdat.object_id, rdat.remote_table_name,
       SUBSTRING(rdat.filter_predicate, 2, LEN(rdat.filter_predicate) - 2) as filter_predicate,
        CASE
        WHEN tbl.remote_data_archive_migration_state_desc = N''''PAUSED'''' THEN 1
        WHEN tbl.remote_data_archive_migration_state_desc = N''''OUTBOUND'''' THEN 3
        WHEN tbl.remote_data_archive_migration_state_desc = N''''INBOUND'''' THEN 4
        WHEN tbl.remote_data_archive_migration_state_desc = N''''DISABLED'''' THEN 0
        ELSE 0
        END AS migration_state
        FROM sys.tables tbl LEFT JOIN sys.remote_data_archive_tables rdat ON rdat.object_id = tbl.object_id
        WHERE rdat.object_id IS NOT NULL'')
        ELSE
        EXECUTE(N''INSERT INTO #tmp_extended_remote_data_archive_tables SELECT rdat.object_id, rdat.remote_table_name,
        SUBSTRING(rdat.filter_predicate, 2, LEN(rdat.filter_predicate) - 2) as filter_predicate,
        CASE
        WHEN rdat.is_migration_paused = 1 AND rdat.migration_direction_desc = N''''OUTBOUND'''' THEN 1
        WHEN rdat.is_migration_paused = 1 AND rdat.migration_direction_desc = N''''INBOUND'''' THEN 2
        WHEN rdat.is_migration_paused = 0 AND rdat.migration_direction_desc = N''''OUTBOUND'''' THEN 3
        WHEN rdat.is_migration_paused = 0 AND rdat.migration_direction_desc = N''''INBOUND'''' THEN 4
        ELSE 0
        END AS migration_state
        FROM sys.tables tbl LEFT JOIN sys.remote_data_archive_tables rdat ON rdat.object_id = tbl.object_id
        WHERE rdat.object_id IS NOT NULL'')
      
 
 
SELECT
tbl.name AS [Name],
tbl.object_id AS [ID],
tbl.create_date AS [CreateDate],
tbl.modify_date AS [DateLastModified],
ISNULL(stbl.name, N'''') AS [Owner],
CAST(case when tbl.principal_id is null then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsSchemaOwned],
SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id) AS [Schema],
CAST(
case 
    when tbl.is_ms_shipped = 1 then 1
    when (
        select 
            major_id 
        from 
            sys.extended_properties 
        where 
            major_id = tbl.object_id and 
            minor_id = 0 and 
            class = 1 and 
            name = N''microsoft_database_tools_support'') 
        is not null then 1
    else 0
end          
             AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id, N''HasAfterTrigger'') AS bit) AS [HasAfterTrigger],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id, N''HasInsertTrigger'') AS bit) AS [HasInsertTrigger],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id, N''HasDeleteTrigger'') AS bit) AS [HasDeleteTrigger],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id, N''HasInsteadOfTrigger'') AS bit) AS [HasInsteadOfTrigger],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id, N''HasUpdateTrigger'') AS bit) AS [HasUpdateTrigger],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id, N''IsIndexed'') AS bit) AS [HasIndex],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id, N''IsIndexable'') AS bit) AS [IsIndexable],
CAST(CASE idx.index_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [HasClusteredIndex],
CAST(ISNULL((select top 1 1 from sys.indexes ind where ind.object_id = tbl.object_id and ind.type > 1 and ind.is_hypothetical = 0 ), 0) AS bit) AS [HasNonClusteredIndex],
CAST(case idx.index_id when 1 then case when (idx.is_primary_key + 2*idx.is_unique_constraint = 1) then 1 else 0 end else 0 end AS bit) AS [HasPrimaryClusteredIndex],
CAST(ISNULL((select top 1 1 from sys.indexes ind where ind.object_id = tbl.object_id and ind.type = 6 and ind.is_hypothetical = 0 ), 0) AS bit) AS [HasNonClusteredColumnStoreIndex],
CAST(ISNULL((select top 1 1 from sys.indexes ind where ind.object_id = tbl.object_id and ind.type = 3 and ind.is_hypothetical = 0 ), 0) AS bit) AS [HasXmlIndex],
CAST(CASE idx.type WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [HasHeapIndex],
CAST(ISNULL((select top 1 1 from sys.all_columns as clmns join sys.types as usrt on usrt.user_type_id = clmns.user_type_id where clmns.object_id = tbl.object_id and usrt.name = N''xml''), 0) AS bit) AS [HasXmlData],
CAST(ISNULL((select top 1 1 from sys.all_columns as clmns join sys.types as usrt on usrt.user_type_id = clmns.user_type_id where clmns.object_id = tbl.object_id and usrt.name in (N''geometry'', N''geography'')), 0) AS bit) AS [HasSpatialData],
tbl.uses_ansi_nulls AS [AnsiNullsStatus],
CAST(ISNULL(OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id,N''IsQuotedIdentOn''),0) AS bit) AS [QuotedIdentifierStatus],
CAST(0 AS bit) AS [FakeSystemTable],
ISNULL(dstext.name,N'''') AS [TextFileGroup],
CAST(tbl.is_memory_optimized AS bit) AS [IsMemoryOptimized],
case when (tbl.durability=1) then 0 else 1 end AS [Durability],
tbl.is_replicated AS [Replicated],
tbl.lock_escalation AS [LockEscalation],
CAST(case when ctt.object_id is null then 0 else 1  end AS bit) AS [ChangeTrackingEnabled],
CAST(ISNULL(ctt.is_track_columns_updated_on,0) AS bit) AS [TrackColumnsUpdatedEnabled],
tbl.is_filetable AS [IsFileTable],
ISNULL(ft.directory_name,N'''') AS [FileTableDirectoryName],
ISNULL(ft.filename_collation_name,N'''') AS [FileTableNameColumnCollation],
CAST(ISNULL(ft.is_enabled,0) AS bit) AS [FileTableNamespaceEnabled],
CASE WHEN ''PS''=dsidx.type THEN dsidx.name ELSE N'''' END AS [PartitionScheme],
CAST(CASE WHEN ''PS''=dsidx.type THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsPartitioned],
CASE WHEN ''FD''=dstbl.type THEN dstbl.name ELSE N'''' END AS [FileStreamFileGroup],
CASE WHEN ''PS''=dstbl.type THEN dstbl.name ELSE N'''' END AS [FileStreamPartitionScheme],
CAST(CASE idx.type WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [HasClusteredColumnStoreIndex],
CAST(CASE tbl.temporal_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsSystemVersioned],
CAST(ISNULL(historyTable.name, N'''') AS sysname) AS [HistoryTableName],
CAST(ISNULL(SCHEMA_NAME(historyTable.schema_id), N'''') AS sysname) AS [HistoryTableSchema],
CAST(ISNULL(historyTable.object_id, 0) AS int) AS [HistoryTableID],
CAST(CASE WHEN periods.start_column_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS [HasSystemTimePeriod],
CAST(
        ISNULL((SELECT cols.name
        FROM sys.columns cols
        WHERE periods.object_id = tbl.object_id
        AND cols.object_id = tbl.object_id
        AND cols.column_id = periods.start_column_id), N'''')
       AS sysname) AS [SystemTimePeriodStartColumn],
CAST(
        ISNULL((SELECT cols.name
        FROM sys.columns cols
        WHERE periods.object_id = tbl.object_id
        AND cols.object_id = tbl.object_id
        AND cols.column_id = periods.end_column_id), N'''')
       AS sysname) AS [SystemTimePeriodEndColumn],
tbl.temporal_type AS [TemporalType],
CAST(tbl.is_remote_data_archive_enabled AS bit) AS [RemoteDataArchiveEnabled],
CAST(
        ISNULL(rdat.migration_state, 0)
       AS tinyint) AS [RemoteDataArchiveDataMigrationState],
CAST(rdat.filter_predicate AS varchar(4000)) AS [RemoteDataArchiveFilterPredicate],
CAST(rdat.remote_table_name AS sysname) AS [RemoteTableName],
CAST(CASE WHEN rdat.remote_table_name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS [RemoteTableProvisioned],
CAST(tbl.is_external AS bit) AS [IsExternal],
CAST(tbl.is_node AS bit) AS [IsNode],
CAST(tbl.is_edge AS bit) AS [IsEdge]
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS stbl ON stbl.principal_id = ISNULL(tbl.principal_id, (OBJECTPROPERTY(tbl.object_id, ''OwnerId'')))
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS idx ON 
        idx.object_id = tbl.object_id and (idx.index_id < @_msparam_0  or (tbl.is_memory_optimized = 1 and idx.index_id = (select min(index_id) from sys.indexes where object_id = tbl.object_id)))
      
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS dstext  ON tbl.lob_data_space_id = dstext.data_space_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.change_tracking_tables AS ctt ON ctt.object_id = tbl.object_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.filetables AS ft ON ft.object_id = tbl.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS dsidx ON dsidx.data_space_id = idx.data_space_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = idx.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS dstbl ON dstbl.data_space_id = t.Filestream_data_space_id and (idx.index_id < 2 or (idx.type = 7 and idx.index_id < 3))
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables as historyTable ON historyTable.object_id = tbl.history_table_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.periods as periods ON periods.object_id = tbl.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmp_extended_remote_data_archive_tables AS rdat ON rdat.object_id = tbl.object_id
WHERE
(tbl.name=@_msparam_1 and SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)=@_msparam_2)
 
        DROP TABLE #tmp_extended_remote_data_archive_tables
      
',
N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000)',
@_msparam_0 = N'2',
@_msparam_1 = N'TABLENAME',
@_msparam_2 = N'SCHEMANAME';

This query takes a long time to execute, but removing the LEFT JOIN on sys.filetables (along with related columns) allows it to run almost instantly.
Is there a way to optimize or work around this behavior, or to fix this problem?
For context:
I have two filetables in the database. Each filetable contains less than 50 records.
I have found that running a SELECT * against either sys.tables or sys.filetables independently completes almost instantly, but running
SELECT *
from sys.tables as tbl
left join sys.filetables as ft on ft.object_id = tbl.object_id

takes 4 minutes for the execution to complete. Though I see the results begin to appear after a few seconds.
Example messages from an execution with statistics io on are below
(29926 row(s) affected)
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 2, logical reads 50935755, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysmultiobjrefs'. Scan count 29926, logical reads 110051, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysidxstats'. Scan count 29926, logical reads 100408, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 523, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'syssingleobjrefs'. Scan count 5, logical reads 325, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'syspalnames'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'syspalvalues'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead read

I think the very high reads on 'sysschobjs' are a cause of this? That internal table has just under 67K rows.
(The actual execution plan for another run is here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJ0EXXAMyg)
The slowest part of the execution plan is below. It estimates that it will scan sysschobjs once but in reality scans it 29952 times. Returning 2 rows per execution but reading 2,004,178,176 in aggregate across all of these scans.


The underlying cardinality estimation problem is visible even if you only select from sys.tables.
The key factor is selecting either of the two retention_period_unit_desc columns. The cardinality estimate suddenly drops to 1 row after an outer join (which can never eliminate rows):

The issue only surfaces as a problem when the erroneous cardinality estimate is used to make a sensitive choice. In your case, that means choosing a nested loops join with an inner side scan on the basis that only one row is expected on the driving input to the nested loops join. When many rows are present at runtime, performance is a disaster as you have observed.
I described the underlying cause over 7 years ago in answer to Why does a subquery reduce the row estimate to 1?
The conditions are:


The join is an outer join with a pass-through predicate
The selectivity of the pass-through predicate is estimated to be exactly 1.


These are met by the two sys.tables view columns mentioned above due to the EXISTS and CASE subqueries in their definitions (see the referenced Q & A for details). Example below:
convert(nvarchar(10),
case when exists (select value from sys.sysobjvalues where valclass = 152 and objid = o.object_id and valnum = 1)
then 
    case (select ISNULL(value, -1) from sys.sysobjvalues where valclass = 152 and objid = o.object_id and valnum = 1)
        when -1 then 'INFINITE'
        when 0 then 'SECOND'
        when 1 then 'MINUTE'
        when 2 then 'HOUR'
        when 3 then 'DAY'
        when 4 then 'WEEK'
        when 5 then 'MONTH'
        when 6 then 'YEAR'
        else 'UNDEFINED'
        end
else
    'INFINITE'
end
) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS as data_retention_period_unit_desc,

This issue appears to have been quietly fixed in SQL Server 2022. There is no documentation for it, and I cannot find a way to enable it on SQL Server 2019. The problem can be reproduced on SQL Server 2022 if one uses a QUERY_OPTIMIZER_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL_150 query hint.
In SQL Server 2019 and earlier, the main workaround is to use different query syntax, for example using NOT EXISTS instead of EXISTS and reversing the CASE clauses.
This is not really an option for system views like sys.tables called from hardcoded SQL in SSMS. It would be much easier if SSMS used user-editable stored procedures for its internal queries.
If you have an instance of SQL Server 2022 around, you could try capturing a plan from there and applying it to 2019 using a plan guide. The plan you want would use something other than a nested loops apply to access the file tables portion of the plan, for example a hash join.
Your other option is to switch to the original cardinality estimation model. This can be done in many ways at different levels of granularity. To test if it resolves the issue with your test query, use a FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION query hint. Again, a plan guide could be used to apply that to the problematic SSMS query.
To give the original CE model its best chance, be sure to update statistics for the underlying system tables (not your user tables) as suggested by Dan Guzman. Example script based on Dan's:
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) =
(
    SELECT
        STRING_AGG
        (
            CONCAT
            (
                N'DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (0,',
                ST.[object_id],
                N') WITH COUNT_ROWS, NO_INFOMSGS;',
                N'UPDATE STATISTICS ',
                QUOTENAME(S.[name]),
                CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'.'),
                QUOTENAME(ST.[name]),
                N' WITH FULLSCAN;'
            ),
            NCHAR(10)
        )
        WITHIN GROUP 
            (ORDER BY ST.[name] ASC)
    FROM sys.objects AS ST
    JOIN sys.schemas AS S
        ON S.[schema_id] = ST.[schema_id]
    WHERE 
        ST.[type_desc] = N'SYSTEM_TABLE'
        AND EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM sys.partitions AS P
            WHERE 
                P.[object_id] = ST.[object_id]
                AND P.[rows] > 0
        )
);
PRINT @SQL;
EXECUTE (@SQL);

Ultimately, this is an issue Microsoft needs to fix in the optimizer and/or SSMS.

I'll check it, thanks for the great answer!
